# GIT Interaction

Tags: version-history, tfs, alm

We use GIT as VCS. For management and for overview, we would like to connect GIT with SharePoint to display metadata of our SW-projects (we do not want to use TFS). Researching on the subject matter is obfuscated by marketing results: we will have a connector or you can vote to get one.
Which possibilities are there, which are you using?